# iOS Submit App to App to App Store via XCode to a foreign iTunes Connect Account

Tags: ios, publish

I need some help.

I want to publish an iOS App to a foreign iTunes Connect Account. The Team Agent of this account has created the required binary information and set it to "Ready for Upload". Now when I want to Submit the App to the Store via XCode it always says "No Application Records were found.. Application must be ready to upload on iTunes Connect before the can be validated or submitted from within XCode."

I am just a member in the Apple Dev Center of this foreign account (I have no account for the iTunes Connect) and downloaded the required Distribution Certifcate and signed the app correctly. That means that bundle identifier and all that stuff has to be OK. Also the version of the App is the same as in iTunes Connect.

Maybe I cannot submit to iTunes Connect because I am only a "member" of this Dev Center? https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php Here it says that only the Agent can Submit to iTunes Connect? Can that be true?

Comment: You have to leep login into developer account before submitting app to AppStore ... so try to first login into developer account and then try to submit the app ..

Comment: I am logged in this developer account while submitting the app besides i am a member of multiple ios dev accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the answer in your question, you must be an Agent to send an application to the AppStore. You can't do this as a Member.

Comment: so even when the application was prepared on iTunes Connect before, by the Agent, I have to be an Agent too, to submit it via XCode?

Comment: Yes, you have to be an Agent

Comment: It' not necessary that only agent can upload the app, member can also upload the app to appstore, for that member should have rights to upload app. visit account setting from itues for more help ...

Comment: ok thank you, I will apply for an Agent, if it works I will accept the answer.

Comment: it seems that it is possible to submit apps without an agent role on behalf of a foreign account. one has to create an new iTunes Connect User following these instructions: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/7_ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH2-SW1

refering the following stack overflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722864/ios-apple-developer-member-center-how-to-submit-apps-on-a-clients-behalf